# QGIS Python plugin crashes when using processing algorithms and QThread

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqt

I'm developing a QGIS plugin which calls several `processing` algorithms. I call them in a pipeline where the input layer of each algo is the output of the previous one. The pipeline is called on each feature of a selected layer where the first step creates a temporary layer in the memory from a feature.

As it's a UI plugin and the algorithms can take some time, I don't want to lock the UI and try to use threads. However, using `QThread`s randomly crashes QGIS.

Here is a minimal code of my plugin.

```
def CreateFeatureLayer(input_layer, feature):
  temp_layer_name = "feature_layer_" + str(feature.id())

  feature_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326", temp_layer_name, "memory")
  feature_layer_data = feature_layer.dataProvider()

  attr = input_layer.dataProvider().fields().toList()
  feature_layer_data.addAttributes(attr)
  feature_layer.updateFields()

  feature_layer_data.addFeature(feature)
  return feature_layer


def BufferFeature(layer):
  result = processing.run("native:buffer", 
  { 'INPUT':layer,
    'DISTANCE':0.0008,
    'SEGMENTS':5,
    'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
    'JOIN_STYLE':0,
    'MITER_LIMIT':2,
    'DISSOLVE':False,
    'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

  buffer_layer = result['OUTPUT']
  return buffer_layer


def MakeDiff(input_layer, buffer_layer):
  result = processing.run("native:difference", 
  { 'INPUT' : buffer_layer,
    'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT',
    'OVERLAY' : input_layer })

  diff_layer = result['OUTPUT']
  return diff_layer

class Worker(QObject):

  start = pyqtSignal()
  success = pyqtSignal(str)

  def __init__(self, selected_layer):
    QObject.__init__(self)
    self._selected_layer = selected_layer

  @pyqtSlot()
  def run(self):
    for f in self._selected_layer.getFeatures():
      feature_layer = CreateFeatureLayer(self._selected_layer, f)
      buffer_layer = BufferFeature(feature_layer)
      diff_layer = MakeDiff(feature_layer, buffer_layer)
    self.success.emit("Success")

class Plugin:

  def WorkerFinished(self, string):
    self._my_worker.deleteLater()
    self._my_thread.quit()
    self._my_thread.wait()
    self._my_thread.deleteLater()

  def run(self):
    selectedLayerIndex = self.dlg.comboBox.currentIndex()
    selectedLayer = self._selectedLayers[selectedLayerIndex].layer()

    self._my_thread = QThread()

    self._my_worker = Worker(selectedLayer)
    self._my_worker.moveToThread(self._my_thread)
    self._my_worker.success.connect(self.WorkerFinished)

    self._my_thread.started.connect(self._my_worker.run)
    self._my_thread.start()
```

Some runs successfully finishes, but there are times where it crashes QGIS randomly.

Calling the pipeline in the main thread (in `Plugin.run()`) doesn't crash QGIS.

Does anyone know what can cause the random crashes?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? If you are using QGIS3 this info can help you https://new.opengis.ch/2018/06/22/threads-in-pyqgis3/

Comment: It's QGIS 3.6.0-Noosa.